# Angular 9 Ivy build - extension errors

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular-ivy

Good morning!

I've recently updated a v8 project to v9, and it seems to work fine. However, I have some extensions and the compiler throws up some errors about them, which it doesn't do in another project that I also recently upgraded.

The extensions are the basic kind, for both constructor and proto. They are set up fine - the same setup works in the multiple projects I have them in. Crucially, they work fine without any errors in the other upgraded project.

However, to get the basic usage confirmations for all out the way:

Adding iface to `typings.d.ts`, e.g.

```
interface StringConstructor {
  isNullOrEmpty(str: string): boolean;
}  
interface String {
  padStartWithChar(char: string, totalSize: number): string;
}
```

Implementation, e.g.

```
export {};

String.isNullOrEmpty = function(str: string): boolean {
  // ...
};

String.prototype.padStartWithChar = function(this: string, char: string, totalSize: number): string {
  // ...
}
```

And importing in `main.ts`

```
// ...
import './extensions/string-extensions';
// ...
```

My paths haven't changed, they all point to all the right files in all the right places that I can think to check for them (`src/typings.d.ts` is in src where I put it, `tsconfig.app.ts` includes it as it did before, etc. etc.).

Which leads to build errors; I get a spam of errors for all usages of the extensions and the build eventually halts:

```
...

src/extensions/string-extensions.ts:9:8 - error TS2339: Property 'isNullOrEmpty' does not exist on type 'StringConstructor'.

9 String.isNullOrEmpty = function(str: string): boolean {

...

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

and attempting to browse results in the `Cannot GET/` basic message. However, it does the usual re-build on saving of files wherein it shows all those error messages again, but completes the build anyway this time and works.

Does anyone have a direction to point me in that I may have missed? Between the two projects I've checked for any significant changes between `angular.json`, `tsconfig`s, `main.ts`, etc. but so far I'm coming up empty.

Thanks.

Edit:

Reverting and attempting the upgrade again, the extensions break at the very first step of the update guide just by running the slight update with `ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`.

From that update onwards, it dies.
Skipping that step (I'm already running a v8 app anyway) and trying to upgrade straight to 9, sadly also kills it.

Update:

Richard's answer seems to have gotten rid of all bar the Date extension error messages.
It doesn't seem to like the existence of a `DateConstructor` interface at all, and it also doesn't seem particularly happy about usages of `moment`, when attempting his method.

Update edit:

Date extensions all look exactly like the other extensions, the singular difference is that there's an `import moment from 'moment'` line in there. Removing such things doesn't seem to make a difference; it's like `Date`s are a different beast to `String`s or `Array`s...

Comment: you must add exclusively
 `"include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]` to your tsconfig.app.json

Comment: @KathakDabhi - Thanks for the reply. Yep, already in there, it's not that.

Comment: What is the parh for your `typings.d.ts` file, make sure it is inside src directory.

Comment: In `src/typings.d.ts`, same place it was before I upgraded.

Comment: @Kremon, I'm able to generate the same error only if I remove the typings.d.ts otherwise it is working fine with Angular 9 project. But you can create new angular 9 project and compare both projects config files to check anything unusual.

Comment: I've been comparing against my other project that I've already upgraded that's working fine with the same extensions and setup. I think when I get back later I'll see what effect moving some files around has - there's some very minor differences in a couple of file locations (but are properly referenced) that I might play with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another project has the error, and I seems I've narrowed it down!

I had build warnings akin to `Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig`.

Having taken a look and comparing my `tsconfig.app.json` file in this newest project I'm updating vs the other, paired with the above warnings, it stood out!

Previous config:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

New config, fixing the warnings (adding the files main and polyfills), and then also fixing the extensions:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "extensions/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Seems one needs to include such files!

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove `export {};` from my implementation file (`extensions.ts`) and repeat the interface.

**extensions.ts**

```
interface String {
  format(...args: string[]): string;
  endsWith(searchString: string, position?: number): boolean;
}

if (!String.prototype.hasOwnProperty('format')) {
    String.prototype.format = function (...args: string[]): string {
        ...
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.hasOwnProperty('endsWith')) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function (searchString, position) {
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: That... seems to have worked! Thank you. No more errors with my string/array/object extensions, but it's not happy about my `Date` extensions. The same fix doesn't seem to apply to those. Have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure, can you update with a code snippet of the date extension

Comment: Not much point, it looks *exactly* like all the other extensions. `Date.xxx = function...` for constructor extensions, `Date.prototype.xxx = function...` for the rest, exactly like the others.

Comment: Think I'll accept defeat on this one and turn my Date extensions into static methods or something instead, unless someone happens to figure it out. Other extensions are fine, at least, so thanks for that, and you can have your answer :)

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, I tested a Date extension in my solution and it worked, so IDK. Double-check the error, maybe it's something different. Thanks for the checkmark!

Comment: No worries, thanks for getting back at all. IDK either! There shouldn't be any errors at all - all the extensions are exact copies of my other, successfully updated to 9, project. Literal copy and paste from *this* project into the other one, in fact.